# Why when the state is updated the changes in the rendering are not updated?

Tags: reactjs, electron, next.js

I have created a hook to access the collections of the database and its methods.

```
import { remote } from 'electron'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

function useCollections(collections = []) {

    let [dbInstances, setDbInstances] = useState(null)
    let [data, setData] = useState(null)

    // DB METHODS

    // Create
    let create = async (doc, dbName) => {
        await dbInstances[dbName].create(doc)
        let newData = await dbInstances[dbName].readAll()
        setData({ ...data, [dbName]: newData })
    }

    // Get details
    let getDetails = async (id, dbName) => {
        let doc = await dbInstances[dbName].read(id)
        return doc
    }

    // Delete
    let deleteOne = async (id, dbName) => {
         await dbInstances[dbName].deleteOne(id)
         let newData = await dbInstances[dbName].readAll()
         setData({ ...data, [dbName]: newData })
    }

    // Update
    let updateOne = async (id, updatedDoc, dbName) => {
        await dbInstances[dbName].archive(id, updatedDoc)
        let newData = await dbInstances[dbName].readAll()
        setData({ ...data, [dbName]: newData })
    }

    // EFFECTS
   
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mounting component')
        let newDBIs = {}
        collections.forEach(col => newDBIs[col] = remote.getGlobal(col))
        console.log('db instances settted', newDBIs)
        setDbInstances(newDBIs)
    }, [])

    // When DBs are instantiated, request all docs and set data with response
    useEffect(() => {
        if (
            dbInstances !== null &&
            data === null &&
            Object.keys(dbInstances).length === collections.length) 
        {
                console.log('setting data')
                let newData = {}
                collections.forEach(async col => newData[col] = await dbInstances[col].readAll())
                console.log('data setted => ', newData)
                setData(newData)
        }
    }, [dbInstances])

    return {
        data,
        create,
        getDetails,
        deleteOne,
        updateOne
    };
}

export default useCollections;
```

In the component where the data returned by the hook is consumed, even though the variable `data` contains the expected data, these are not rendered.

```
import WindowsLayout from "../../components/layout/WindowsLayout"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { remote } from "electron"
import useCollections from "../../hooks/useCollections"

const EditWorkWindow = ({ workId }) => {

    let { data, deleteOne, updateOne } = useCollections([
        'workDB',
        'studioDB',
        'rateDB'
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data !== null) console.log(data)
    }, [data])

   
    return (
        <WindowsLayout title="Edit work window">
            <div style={{ height: 243 }} className="window-content">
                <div className="padded-more bg-gray-200">
                   <h2>{JSON.stringify(data)}</h2>
                   <button onClick={() => console.log(data)}>CLG</button>          
                </div>
            </div>
        </WindowsLayout >
    )
}

export default EditWorkWindow
```

The effect hook shows the expected data by console.

`<h2>{JSON.stringify(data)}</h2>` = `{}`

When the button is clicked, the expected data is displayed on the console.

I can't understand why if data contains properties, they are not shown in `{JSON.stringify(data)}`

This is what is shown by the console after clicking on the button
[console.log(data) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neDb5.png)

And this is example `data` and their its properties

```
{
   "workDB":[
      {
         "product":"Work name 1",
         "amounts_rates":[
            {
               "rate":"EflcQflqu2oWWVk2",
               "amount":6
            },
            {
               "rate":"FeMIX00pwpmZwoVW",
               "amount":1
            }
         ],
         "date":"2020-08-31",
         "studio":"BCvPeWzMiS8fZsmS",
         "_id":"2ZvHMWFODBHYWEBo",
         "createdAt":"2020-08-31T09:39:21.077Z",
         "updatedAt":"2020-08-31T09:39:21.077Z"
      },
      {
         "product":"Work name 2",
         "amounts_rates":[
            
         ],
         "date":"2020-09-02",
         "director":"",
         "_id":"PRpp1OQcJnkFKeR0",
         "createdAt":"2020-09-01T19:56:33.201Z",
         "updatedAt":"2020-09-01T19:56:33.201Z"
      }
   ],
   "studioDB":[
      {
         "name":"Studio name 1",
         "_id":"0J1AVXtgDjwBjRS9",
         "createdAt":"2020-08-25T10:18:40.004Z",
         "updatedAt":"2020-08-25T10:18:40.004Z"
      },
      {
         "name":"Studio name 2",
         "_id":"8sFH7gncaM6V7lHh",
         "createdAt":"2020-08-25T10:19:45.232Z",
         "updatedAt":"2020-08-25T10:19:45.232Z"
      }
   ],
   "rateDB":[
      {
         "name":"Rate name 1",
         "value":4.1,
         "_id":"EflcQflqu2oWWVk2",
         "createdAt":"2020-08-25T10:24:17.357Z",
         "updatedAt":"2020-08-25T10:24:17.357Z"
      },
      {
         "name":"Rate name 1",
         "value":34,
         "_id":"FeMIX00pwpmZwoVW",
         "createdAt":"2020-08-25T10:24:25.628Z",
         "updatedAt":"2020-08-25T10:24:25.628Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what `data` contains when you log it? Is it possible it's an inherited object that has now "own" properties but only the superclass does? Or the ones it does have are not JSON serializable

Comment: Thank you for your comment casraf , I have edited the question and added an image with what `console.log(data)` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async problem it is.

```js
// When DBs are instantiated, request all docs and set data with response
    useEffect(() => {
        if (
            dbInstances !== null &&
            data === null &&
            Object.keys(dbInstances).length === collections.length) 
        {
                console.log('setting data')
                let newData = {}
                collections.forEach(async col => newData[col] = await dbInstances[col].readAll())
                console.log('data setted => ', newData)

                setData(newData) // <-- LOOK HERE

        }
    }, [dbInstances])
```

So you `let newData = {}` empty object, and send it off to trigger an update re-render by calling `setData()`, but `newData` is empty at the moment of calling.

In your rendering function `JSON.stringify(data)` pickup the data, but it's still empty at the moment of rendering!

It's only when `async col => newData[col] = await someValue` call is resolved, that your `newData`'s **properties** will get assigned new values, the `newData` object stays the same. But by the time it's resolved, the rendering is done already.

Solution: wait till async function call is resolved, then you call `setData()`

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...
    const promises = collections.map(async col => {
        newData[col] = await dbInstances[col].readAll())
    })
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => { setData(newData) })
})
```

The reason why you see the updated value when inspecting in console, is because you didn't inspect "quick enough". By the time you mouse-click to expand the object in console, its properties are already assigned values. But if you change

```
console.log('data setted => ', newData) 
// to
console.log('data setted => ', JSON.stringify(newData))
```

you'll see an empty object.

Comment: Great answer! Very well explained, it has solved my problem. Thank you very much!